# str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, " ") erases my whole string instead of just getting rid of non-numerical characters. How to make it work properly?

Tags: javascript, html, string, input, replace

I'm trying to use str.replace in order to remove any non-numerical characters from a number imput field when someone uses copy-pastes something in it. However the function always seems to remove all characters instead of just removing the non-numerical ones.

Surprisingly the function is able to detect when my string is purely numerical and won't change it in those cases, but adding a single other character will cause the whole string to be ditched instead of just removing the wrong characters.

I tried to change the regexp of the function to /\D/, but it didn't amount much.

Here's a minimal reproducible example, which must be run on Firefox.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px;">
        <script src="../lib/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <input type="number" id="inp"></input>
        <script>
            let input = document.getElementById("inp");
            input.onblur = function()
            {
                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect an output such as "34a01 2" to be "34012", but the actual output is "" (nothing). Is there something wrong in my regexp ?

```js
let input = document.getElementById("inp");
input.onblur = function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="inp"></input>
```

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.

I can only type digits in the inputbox.

Comment: Not related: you don't need `$(document).ready` for `onblur` event

Comment: @Pitto It's not when you type. It's when you copy-paste inside of it. I want any non-numerical character removed when you blur the input field, but it does not just remove non-numerical stuff, it removes numerics as well.

Comment: Also copy / paste works fine.
Please check my answer below, @Eox
Also the post code in the example (now it is possible to run it) works just fine for me.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Tried the same thing you did : didn't work for me. Could it be related to the navigator or the operating system I'm using ? I'm currently doing that with firefox on a linux computer.

Comment: On Firefox I see: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Be sure that you are loading your dependecies well.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {` needs to be on the outside. You're also not using jQuery for anything else. While there are in theory use-cases for assigning an event handler inside another one, it's bad practice and not required here. Here's live code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fj1u3wbk/ If you remove the `number` type and change it from `blur` to `input`, it'll prevent typing non-numbers in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read your comments about Firefox and I've prepared a new version.

Not including the "number" type seems to work.

Using "number" type is not causing any issue in Chrome so I guess that Firefox is not behaving in the same way.

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body style="margin:0px;">
            <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <input id="inp"></input>
            <script>
                let input = document.getElementById("inp");
                input.onblur = function() {
                    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work on my end. The issue must be somewhere else. Perhaps it is related to my navigator (Firefox) or my OS ?

EDIT : JQuery seems to load fine. I can't seem to find any error on the console.

Comment: Good point, @Eox.

I downloaded Firefox and was able to reproduce the issue. 

Please check this new version.

Comment: I am happy to read that, @Eox.

In case this code was useful for you please don't forget to upvote and / or accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be a Firefox issue (or bug). Whenever a numeric input has non-numeric characters anywhere, the `.value` of the field will be the empty string:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(input.value);
}, 400);
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number">
```

It's unfortunate, but you may have to simply remove the `type="number"` for the `.value` to be retrieved and replaced as desired:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("inp");
input.onblur = function() {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp"></input>
```

Either that, or keep `type="number"` and tell the user that the value they attempted to paste is invalid, and prevent it (because you have no way of retrieving and replacing it).

(also: only call `$(document).ready` *once*, when you're adding the listeners, if at all - your current code is adding a new listener every time the field is blurred)

Comment: Firefox issue. Got it. I'll try to find a workaround then. Thank you all for all the help. :)